# Prime divisors of $60!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, factorial

> How to find all prime divisors of $60!$?, where $60!$ denotes the factorial of $60$, the product all integers from $1$ to $60$.

Is there any solution to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: $p$ divides a product of numbers iff it divides one of them

Comment: $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59$.

Comment: Remember: if $n$ is a positive integer, then $n!$ is divisible by all the positive primes less than $n$. In this case, that means $2, 3, 5, 7, \ldots, 59$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember: if $n$ is a positive integer, then $n!$ is divisible by all the positive primes less than $n$. In this case, that means $2, 3, 5, 7, \ldots, 59$.

Now, do you need to find just the *distinct* prime divisors? If so, you're done. If you also need to count up how often each prime divisor occurs, you've got a bit of work to do. It's tedious but not difficult. Observe:

- $2! = 2$
- $3! = 2 \times 3$
- $4! = 2 \times 3 \times 4 = 2^3 \times 3$. Observe that since $4 = 2^2$, we need to add $2$ to the (previously unwritten) exponent $1$ that $2$ had.
- $5! = 2^3 \times 3 \times 5$. Since $5$ is prime, we can just carry over the previous factorization append the "$\times 5$" at the end.
- $6! = 2^4 \times 3^2 \times 5$. Since $6$ is divisible by $2$ and $3$, we need to increment the exponents for both of those primes.
- $7! = 2^4 \times 3^2 \times 5 \times 7$. Since $7$ is prime, we can just carry over the previous factorization append the "$\times 7$" at the end.
- ...
- $60! = 2^{56} \times 3^{28} \times 5^{14} \times 7^{19} \times \ldots \times 47 \times \times 53 \times 59$.

Actually, come to think of it, I think there's a formula that will give you the exponent of each prime without having to go through this "reverse engineering" of the factorial. So yeah, there is a solution to this problem, more than one of them, in fact.

Answer (score 5):

Since $60!$ is just the product of first $60$ natural numbers so the only prime numbers which would divide $60!$ are those which are smaller than $60$.

Proof of statements used.

> $1$. Only prime numbers which divide $60! $ are smaller than $60$, no prime greater than $60$ can divide $60!$.

Let's say that a prime ($p$) which is greater than $60$ divides $60!$. Now $60!$ is product of first $60$ consecutive natural numbers as $1.2.3.4.5......60$ and what we are saying  is that $p|1.2.3.4.5......60$. Now a prime number can only divide itself and  its multiple and since our prime $p$ is greater than $60$ so there is nothing in $1.2.3.4.5......60$ which $p$ can divide. A contradiction.

> $2$. All the prime numbers smaller than $ 60$ divide $60!$.

It is quite easy to prove, as $60!=1.2.3.4.5......60$, so every prime smaller than $60$ come in $1.2.3.4.5......60$ and hence every prime smaller than $60$ divide $60!=1.2.3.4.5......60$

:) :)

Comment: Not every "product of $60$ natural numbers" (quoting from your answer) is divisible only by prime numbers smaller than $60$.

Comment: I edited it @barakmanos, Thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: OK, but I think that a thorough (and more formal) answer would be to prove that **every** prime below $60$ divides $60!$ and **every** prime larger than $60$ does not divide $60!$. This answer is basically just explaining what $60!$ means, which is (or should be) obvious to most readers (and of course, the question is pointless for someone who does not understand what "$!$" means in this context). But then again, the question is very basic, so I'm not quite sure that and elaborated and thorough answer would be extremely useful here...

Comment: @barakmanos So tell me the conclusion. Should I prove the both ??

Comment: It's up to you really. I wouldn't bother to answer the question otherwise. You have not really explained anything IMO (apart from what $60!$ means).

Comment: @barakmanos, okay now??

Comment: "a prime number can only divide itself and its multiple" - that statement is true for every number.

Comment: Yeah it is .... I think since I m answering a question involving prime so using the term prime number is appropriate here.

Comment: I meant to say that it seems pointless to denote this fact (which derives directly from the definitions of *multiplication* and *division*).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $60!=1\cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdots 60$.

It is easy to see that 2 is a prime divisor, 3, 5, 7, ... all primes up to 60.

Answer (score 1):

Three simple observations should make this very obvious:

1)  If $k < n$ then $n! = 1*2*.....*(k-1)*k*.......n$ so $k|n!$.  So all primes less than $60$ will be prime factors of $60$.

2) If $p$ is prime, and $p > k$ then $p \not \mid k$.  So if $p > n$ then $p \not \mid k$ for any $k \le n$.

3) $n! = \prod_k^n k = \prod_k^n (\text{unique prime factorization of }k)$ so $n!$ has as prime factors *only* the same prime factors of the $k \le n$.

.....

Therefore 1) all primes less or equal to $60$ will be factors and 2) no primes greater than $60$ will be factors. 
The more interesting question is what is the prime factorization of $60!$.  You *do* have enough information to solve that.

Comment: ...'so the prime factors are 2, 3, 5, and 7'.  There are a LOT of other primes smaller than 60?

Comment: D'oh!  That was an unbelievable stupid thing for me to have said, wasn't it?  Gad.... Where is my freaking brain?  (I was thinking of primes whose squares ware less than 60.  *Why* I was thinking of primes whose squares were less than 60 is unknown .....)

Comment: After all this years I still don't trust myself to have all the primes memorized to whenever I find myself thinking "Is 131 prime? It seems prime" I always do a quick sieve "Obviously not divisible by 2,3,5.  140 - 7 =133 so not seven.  11^2 =1 21 so not 11,and 13^2 > 131 so done.  It's prime".  So when I thought "list all primes less than 60" the force of habit made me think "2,3,5,7 and 8^2 > 60.  So done."  D'oh! D'oh! D'oh!.  I'm used to making careless mistakes but that one.... that was a whopper!